# How to check if any entity contains specified string on any field?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How to check if any entity contains specified string on any field?

Let's assume that we have many entities like Blog, News, Article etc. Each entity can have some fields, like title, content, author etc. But not all entities have the same fields. They can be different. And now we want to check if there is entity which contains "cat" on any from their fields. It is important that I don't want to get these entities. I want to only know if there is entity like that.

This is because I have text editor (like MCE) which allows to upload files and place them (URLs) directly into the edited field. For example: images in message body or in article content. So I have mechanism to upload files, but I don't have any knowledge if the uploaded file is still needed or I can remove them, because after deleting entity, files are not deleted.

Therefore I'm trying to check if filename is used in any entity on any field. Of course I can do something like that:

```
$builder = $this->manager->createQueryBuilder();
$builder->select('COUNT(blog)');
$builder->from('AppBundle:Blog', 'blog');
$builder->where('blog.content LIKE :term');
$builder->setParameter('term', '%' . $file->getFilename() . '%');
```

But this way, I have to remember to add query like that for each field which is editable by text editor. I don't want to have to remember.

I'm looking for simple and elastic solution. I think about SOLR, but the number of entities will be to low for SOLR. It doesn't has sense for me - is like killing mosquito with bazuka (Bad example. That just makes sense - cursed mosquitoes. But you know).

I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine.

Any ideas?